# Fetching multiple states with Zustand/React (shorthand syntax)

Tags: reactjs, zustand

Are both ways of fetching states from the ***Zustand*** store identical in respect of re-renders on state changes?

Method described in the **documentation**:

```js
const nuts = useStore(state => state.nuts)
const honey = useStore(state => state.honey)
```

**Shorthand:**

```js
const { nuts, honey } = useStore()
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Short Answer

No, these methods are not identical.

### Long Answer

As mentioned in the [zustand readme](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand#fetching-everything):

> Fetching everything
>
> You can, but bear in mind that it will cause the component to update
> on every state change!
>
> const state = useStore()

So, When you select certain slices of state using a selector, the component will only update/rerender when the selected values change.

When you call `useStore()` without passing any parameters to it, you are effectively subscribing your component to the whole state. As a metaphor, you could say that "zustand will be asking the component to update/rerender on any state change, anywhere in the state tree". Object destructuring in the shorthand syntax is just syntactic sugar to assign variables to object properties in a quicker way. The value that `useStore()` returns (and subscribes the component to) is still the whole state.

So, if you use `const { nuts, honey } = useStore()`, you may run into performance issues. Whether those issues will be noticeable or not depends on the app, but I'd say it's easy enough to just use selectors and not have to worry about it.

### Further suggestion

If you need to select all the slices of state in a single `useStore(...)` call, the recommended method is to use suitable selectors for that.
Quoting from [Selecting multiple state slices](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand#selecting-multiple-state-slices)

```
import shallow from 'zustand/shallow'

// Object pick, re-renders the component when either state.nuts or state.honey change
const { nuts, honey } = useStore(state => ({ nuts: state.nuts, honey: state.honey }), shallow)

// Array pick, re-renders the component when either state.nuts or state.honey change
const [nuts, honey] = useStore(state => [state.nuts, state.honey], shallow)

// Mapped picks, re-renders the component when state.treats changes in order, count or keys
const treats = useStore(state => Object.keys(state.treats), shallow)
```

Comment: i love zustand but man this syntax is pretty rough to use, especially since "shallow" doesn't like to be auto imported in VSCode

Comment: What about using 'getState' like 'const foo = useStore.getState().foo'. does get state also fetch everything which will cause the component to re-render on every state change ?

Answer (score 9):

No, they are not identical: the first will re-render only when the selected properties change; and the second will re-render whenever any property of the store changes.

The motivation for the question seems to be to avoid the verbosity of fetching multiple states with Zustand (as [ICW also commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68609189/fetching-multiple-states-with-zustand-react-shorthand-syntax#comment128400624_68914297), this can be a pain.)

You can achieve a more concise syntax for multiple zustand imports in a couple of different ways.

#### Option 1

Let's define this helper function:

```js
function useMulti(useFunc, ...items) {
  return items.reduce((carry, item) => ({
    ...carry,
    [item]: useFunc(state => state[item]),
  }), {})
}
```

After defining this wrapper function, instead of writing this:

```js
const {nuts, honey} = useStore(state => ({
  nuts: state.nuts,
  honey: state.honey,
}), shallow)
```

you can write this:

```js
const {nuts, honey} = useMulti(useStore, 'nuts', 'honey')
```

The wrapper function is just providing some syntactic sugar for selecting multiple states.

- Note that internally, `useMulti` uses a separate `useStore` call for each asked-for prop. Therefore, state invalidation is equivalent to using `zustand/shallow` without `useMulti`.
- Also note that `useMulti` only works for top-level properties of the store: you would need a more complicated `useMulti` implementation if you want to fetch `state.x.y.z`, for example.

If you don't like the functional call style of `useMulti(useStore(...))`, you can leverage `useMulti()` to create a wrapper function for `useStore()` specifically:

```js
export const useStoreMulti = (...items) => useMulti(useStore, ...items)
```

This allows you to write

```js
const {nuts, honey} = useStoreMulti('nuts', 'honey')
```

#### Option 2

It can be cleaner to just import them separately. This is particularly true if you're selecting many different store props: consider the following, where zustand is quite verbose:

```js
const {
  nuts,
  honey,
  salmon,
  berries,
  fruit,
  insects,
  carrion,
  newbornElk,
  roots,
  garbage,
} = useStore(state => ({
  nuts: state.nuts,
  honey: state.honey,
  salmon: state.salmon,
  berries: state.berries,
  fruit: state.fruit,
  insects: state.insects,
  carrion: state.carrion,
  newbornElk: state.newbornElk,
  roots: state.roots,
  garbage: state.garbage,
}), shallow)
```

vs this, which is broadly equivalent:

```js
const nuts = useStore(state => state.nuts)
const honey = useStore(state => state.honey)
const salmon = useStore(state => state.salmon)
const berries = useStore(state => state.berries)
const fruit = useStore(state => state.fruit)
const insects = useStore(state => state.insects)
const carrion = useStore(state => state.carrion)
const newbornElk = useStore(state => state.newbornElk)
const roots = useStore(state => state.roots)
const garbage = useStore(state => state.garbage)
```

One way to reduce the number of characters per call here is to define a local helper:

```js
const localUse = (prop) => useStore(state => state[prop])

const nuts = localUse('nuts')
const honey = localUse('honey')
const salmon = localUse('salmon')
const berries = localUse('berries')
const fruit = localUse('fruit')
const insects = localUse('insects')
const carrion = localUse('carrion')
const newbornElk = localUse('newbornElk')
const roots = localUse('roots')
const garbage = localUse('garbage)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Benji XVI response, I would propose the same implementation working with typescript:

```
// Utility function, to allow us to pick fields from the store
const useMulti = <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
  useStoreFn: UseBoundStore<StoreApi<T>>,
  ...items: K[]
): Pick<T, K> => {
  return items.reduce(
    (carry, item) => ({
      ...carry,
      // No need to use useShallow here, as we fetch the objects one by one
      [item]: useStoreFn((state) => state[item]),
    }),
    {}
  ) as Pick<T, K>;
}
```

Then, the wrapper:

```
// Wrapper store hook
const useStoreMulti = (...items: Array<keyof StoreType>) =>
  useMulti(useStore, ...items)
```

So in the end, you can access your store with the following:

```
const {nuts,honey} = useStoreMulti("nuts","honey")
```

You can check this [live example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/contexts-x8w2jj?file=%2FREADME.txt%3A36%2C208) that I did if you want to play around

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution?

```
const {nuts,honey} = useStoreMulti();
```

https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/discussions/1308

Comment: Yes, what about it? What is the effect? Why do you think it might help? Which doubts do you have? What kind of testing do you want others to do for you on it? Do you need any help or explanation with why that does not provide an answer according to [answer] to this question?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

throwing my 2 cents here.

Even though I like the previous answers ([Benji XVI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196312/benji-xvi) and [TheTisiboth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13434259/thetisiboth)), using a custom function to give you back the state pieces you want, they fail at one thing: [They break the rules of Hooks](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning).

They are calling the `useStore` function inside a callback, which according to the React Docs is invalid, and ESLint will complain.

Instead, what I did was calling the store at the top of the custom hook, and use reduce to create an object inside the `useShallow`.

Like this:

```js
import { useShallow } from "zustand/react/shallow";
// Replace this with your actual store and type
import { StoreType, useZustandStore} from "../lib/store";

export function useMulti<T extends StoreType, K extends keyof StoreType>(...items: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
  const obj = useZustandStore(
    useShallow((state) => items.reduce((acc, item) => ({ ...acc, [item]: state[item] }), {}))
    );
  return obj as Pick<T, K>;
}
```

So then you call the function like this

```js
import { useMulti } from "../hooks/useMulti";

const { value1, value2 } = useMulti("value1", "value2");
```

And it should work as expected, re-rendering only where it should, and with a code that's easy on the eyes.

And if you want this hook to be reusable with every other store, then you have to pass the store as an argument to the hook, just like [Benji XVI's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196312/benji-xvi) example, and you're golden.

Hope it helps!